# How to receive blob response type from axios request with Node and GCP Function

Tags: node.js, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble using a axios get request to receive a CSV and parse it using a google cloud function. The following code works running locally and in a docker container, but not in GCP function for reasons that have me stumped, it does not even throw a error, just says function ran ok, even if I try to catch the error nothing logs to console. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(
    'http-endpoint-with-csv'
  );

  return data.data;
};

getData().then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Is your endpoint from a third-party? Third-party requests require billing to be enabled.

Comment: It is a third party and I do have billing enabled, currently have $290 in free credit as well. I have tried regular requests that return json and they work fine, just not http endpoints that just download a csv if you go to them in the browser.

Comment: Can you add your full `index` file? Maybe it's something around this code that's causing the issue (e.g. function resolves before work has completed).